# Whatsapp and Einstein Bots - Am I forgetting some configuration?

Tags: integration, einstein, bot

I'm participating in a project with a Chatbot integration with Whatsapp via Salesforce. I've never worked with it before so it's been a challenge. We did all the setup up to phone confirmation (which we did via call with a Salesforce expert). WhatsApp appeared in the system, I was able to add it to the chatbot and from there nothing happened. I must be missing something, can anyone help me??

When I use Preview everything works ok. But when I go to whatsapp and send a message, nothing happens. Whatsapp is with my client so I don't know if any extra configuration is needed there before enabling the bot.

[image]

(failed attempts lol)
[image]